# Sony Camera Remote API, NEX-5 Model preview not updating

Tags: android, mobile, camera, sony

I am using the default sample App for Android for Sony Camera Remote API. It is working fine but for Nex-5T Model, the preview is not showing (updating) properly. The Same App is working fine for DSC-QX10 model without any issue.

The Sony Play Memories app is working fine for both the Camera models.
Is there anything we need to do for Nex-5 model.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the Liveview size and external Wi-Fi interference issues to troubleshoot the issues you are reporting with NEX-5T. Also please check if you have the latest versions of camera firmware and 'Smart Remote Control' app.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team

Comment: I am using it in Samsung S4, and there is no Wi-FI interference as the camera and mobile are placed very near by. While using through PlayMemories App its showing properly.

Comment: If the device under test is same, the only difference I can think of is the Liveview size.

Comment: The Live view works till we get a snap from remote, there after its getting struck. Liveview is not modified anything from the sample Application.

Comment: Dear Ajay, I am not aware of similar issue with camera and you mentioned before QX10 did not have this issue only 5T. Is this still the case? Any more progress? Best Regards, Prem

Comment: Yes Nex-5T model only has this issue but randomly (not every time) and  QX10 works smoothly.